# Policy Maturity

Tags: logical-deduction

Atul has 6 policy accounts which are going to mature in between the
years 1997 to 2002 (both the years included). Two
policies have their maturity in the same month whereas
two policies have their maturity in the same year. One
of the policies matures on Feb 29th. It matures before
the policy which matures on January 10th but after the
policy which matures on August 8th. The first policy
matures on August 24th 1997. The policy which
matures on September 17th matures immediately
before the policy which matures on May 21st which
in turn is the last policy to mature.

1. Which of the following policies is the 3rd to
   mature?
   (1) Feb 29th, 2000 (2) Jan 10th, 2001
   (3) August 8th, 1999 (4) August 8th 1998

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think the answer is (1) because:
>   1) 24th August 1997 (by definition)
>   2) 8th August 1998 (before (3))
>   3) 29th Feb 2000 (the only leap year in the interval)
>   4) 10th Jan 2001 ((3) is before this one)
>   5) 17th Sep 2001 (before the last by definition)
>   6) 21st May 2002 (last by definition)
>  We have two policies in 2001 and two in August (same month but different years, still it fulfills the requirement)

Comment: Just adding that rot13 (gur frpbaq cbyvpl pbhyq or bar avar avar avar nf jryy)